# $\cos x\cdot \sin x$ integral problem

Tags: calculus, integration

When integrating $\cos x\cdot \sin x$ it is found that this function could be the derivative of $3$ different possible functions ...

My question is, would that be considered a mathematical uncertainty?

Comment: It is the derivative of an _infinite_ number of functions, all differing by a constant... Depending on the approach of finding the anti-derivative, they may seem very different - but they aren't.

Comment: Probably the difference comes just from the fact that $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I am getting different answer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393098/why-i-am-getting-different-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers look different, they are all equivalent anti-derivatives as each differs by a constant amount from the others.

Recall the identity $\sin^{2} x + \cos^{2} x = 1$. We can re-write this as $\sin^{2} x = 1 – \cos^{2} x.$.

---

So the answer of $\frac{\sin2 x}{2}$ + C can be written as $\frac{1 – \cos2 x}{2}$ + C = $\frac{1}{2} – \frac{\cos2 x}{2}$ + C. The constant $\frac{1}{2}$ can be grouped with the arbitrary constant C to give :$\frac{\cos 2x}{2}$ + C. In other words, we’ve determined these two answers are equivalent.

---

So the third answer of -$\frac{\cos(2x)}{4}$ + C can be re-written as: $\frac{2 \cos2 x – 1}{4}$ + C = -$\frac{\cos2 x}{4}$ + $\frac{1}{4}$ + C. The constant $\frac{1}{4}$ can be grouped with the arbitrary constant C so the answer is -$\frac{\cos2 x}{2}$ + C, and so this answer is also equivalent to the other answers.

---

In fact if you draw the graphs of all the three anti-derivatives, we get,
 [image].

As you can see, the graphs are all vertical translations of one another–each function differs from another by a constant amount.

Anti-derivatives that differ by a constant are equivalent to each other, and so the solutions are really $3$ ways of writing the same anti-derivative. Hope it helps.

Comment: that helped, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider the formulae
$$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1\quad\text{or}\quad \sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\biggl(\sum_{k=1}^n k\biggr)^2$$
as reflecting a ‘mathematical uncertainty’?

Answer (score 0):

There's a mathematical *ambiguity*, but no uncertainty. Let me try to explain:

We speak informally of "the integral of $f$", typically meaning the indefinite integral. The Fundamental Theorem tells us that generally this indefinite integral is a function $F$ with $F' = f$. But in saying this, I've already led you down the garden path, for "the indefinite integral" is meaningless -- it's *an* indefinite integral. For any function $F$ that has the property that $F' = f$, and any constant $C$, there's another function
$$
G(x) = F(x) + C
$$
that *also* has the property that $G' = f$, i.e., it's another indefinite integral of $F$.

So why do we talk about "the indefinite integral"? Because it's convenient, and everyone who uses it on a regular basis knows that they're being informal "up to constants". But that doesn't help the beginner one bit!